# Showed object number is not correct

Tags: qgis

[image]In the attribute table for a layer I have 13 Objects and if I switch on object number button. I have 16 Objects and this is wrong. I couldn´t find a way to correct this?

On the left side you see VK with 16 objects, but in the drawing there are only 13 red circles.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the issue. Please add a picture.

Comment: The object numbering might contain objects that are already deleted. They still are in the shapefile's database, but hidden.

Comment: are you in an edit session ?

Comment: @AndreJ: That could be right. So is there a way to delete the hidden objects?

Comment: @kwoxer: I add a picture.

Comment: @radouxju:No, i am not in an edit session

Comment: The added picture is not visible. Saving to another file format, like spatialite, will leave out deleted objects. I am not sure if saving to another file name already does the trick.

Comment: @AndreJ: Thank you. That´s not necessary, because I saved it as ESRI-Shapefile as normally. The Result is that the objectnumber is now correct, but this should be not the correct way, because now I have to change the properties once again. Is there a other way to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object numbering might contain objects that are already deleted. They still are in the shapefile's database, but hidden.

Saving to another file name or file format, like spatialite, will leave out deleted objects.

To preserve your layer styling, you can copy the style from the old layer to the new one, then delete the old layer from the canvas.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, but I am very new to Qgis. How can i copy the style from the old layer to the new one??

Comment: Right-click on your layer, then inside menu 'Style': click the 'Style' drop-down menu (at the bottom of the dialog) and eventually select 'Save Style > QGIS Layer style file'. This will produce a *.qml file. To set this style to your new layer, follow the same steps but select 'Load style' in the drop-down menu. Hope it's clear enough!

Comment: Thank you that works fine. see my picture. "testfile" is a copy of "Hausanschluß". "Testfile" has 114 Object and "Hausanschluß" has 122 Object. The difference are deleted Objects.

Comment: Alternatively, you have a `Style`entry in the rightclick context menu, where you can copy and paste without saving the style to a file.

Answer (score 2):

If you close and re-open your project, the displayed number will be updated. If you remove and then add the layer again, the option 'Show feature count' is no longer activated.

Comment: sorry, but it dosn`t work. I closed the file und reopen it as you mentioned, but I have already 16 Objects. Also, when i remove the shapelayer and bring the layer again to Qgis 2.8.1. I have 16 Objects. It seem´s that the only way is to save the layer with another file name.

Comment: Do you mean closing the project or the layer? I have QGIS 2.8.1 and this works by closing the project... Anyway, good that you could find an answer.

Comment: I mean closing the project. But anyway thank you for your help